# Pulling my hair out at Generic Error Message

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `dataflow` which is a `SharePoint List Source` to `ADO.NET Database Destination` . In `SSIS 2008`, when I run this I get the Error below. I have been through the 40 columns I am bringing through and checked the input size and the size of the database columns and they look fine. Point to note is that I am using memo fields to ntext data type. The result set sought is 600 rows imported from SharePoint List . I run this data flow and I get the Error below, only 200 get written to the database out of 600 that need to get imported.

3 Interesting tests.

- Test 1, increasing the buffer size to 30 million , I now get 390 rows
  imported, then I get the Error below.
- Test 2, Upping the value to 50
  million causes the error to happen straight away. I have not touched
  the batch size which is 2000.
- Test 3, I unmap a few random columns
  in the middle of the SharePoint list source and all the rows now get
  imported.

I do not understand what is going on. It seems I am hitting some kind of internal limit, is this a SharePoint adaptor problem ?

Error

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DoesNotFitBufferException: The value is too large to fit in the column data area of the buffer.

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer.SetString(Int32 columnIndex, String value)

   at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListSource.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPrimeOutput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, IDTSBuffer100[] buffers, IntPtr ppBufferWirePacket)
```

Comment: I would try lowering the batch size.   Also check the advanced properties of the data source and see what SSIS data type your memo fields are being cast as inside the package data flow.

Comment: The Scientific Method is going to be your friend here. Change one thing and test. Repeat until you've identified what is causing the failure.

Comment: The error you are encountering is in the population of the buffer (what's coming out of the sharepoint adapter). You could remove your destination and would continue to get the same results.

Comment: As @billinkc said, your buffer is running out of memory.  It sounds like you have very limited resources on your SSIS server (or laptop).  You could configure the data flow property BufferTempStoragePath to give it a place to spill to disk.  I forget if ntext is treated as binary, but you might need to consider BlobTempStoragePath as well.

Comment: I don't know that it's a matter of the pipeline running out of memory so much as trying to stuff 5lbs of data into a 1lb sack

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. The source for sp list source says a field is 100 when it is 150 in real life. So frustrating. Changed the field size on the source.